# What is this usage of "with"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I wrote this sentence in a paper about computer science:

> Then these cells are divided into groups, with cells in each group being shared among the same set of processes.

It sounds correct to me, but since I'm not a native speaker of English, I don't trust my intuition completely. So I searched for this usage of "with" in a few dictionaries but didn't find it. Still, the sentence sounds correct.

Obviously, the sentence can be separated into two parts:

1. Then these cells are divided into groups.
2. The cells in each group are shared among the same set of of processes.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you asking for the name of this usage? Or whether it is grammatical? How did you want "with" to be understood in the sample sentence you wrote?

Comment: ***...with** cells in each group **being** shared...* is just alternative phrasing for ***...where** cells in each group **are** shared...*

Comment: My vtc was to migrate this to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), not to close it as a duplicate of a similar previous question that was closed as Off Topic (presumably, for being "Too Basic" for this site).

Comment: @Lawrence, I felt that it is grammatical and I wanted to check it against grammar rules. I think when a well-educated native English speaker feels intuitively that some sentence is grammatical, it is almost certainly grammatical. She doesn't need to study syntax. But for someone like me, whose intuition about English is not reliable, knowing detailed grammar rules and doing syntactical analysis can be very helpful.

Comment: @apadana Thank you for that information. [ELL] does more of that analysis than EL&U, which caters more for those already fluent in English. Note, though, that both communities are part of Stack Exchange, which expects questions to include information about 'how far you got'. This lets the community skip over information you already have, and filters out requests to 'do my homework for me'. ...

Comment: ... The question must also be clear. In this case, you're asking the community to tell you how a word is used, but the word "usage" in the question's title is too broad to be useful. Telling you it is a preposition is unhelpful, but it's not clear what kind of "usage" you want to discuss. Adding this information to the question would help with clarity.

Comment: The question "Is this grammatical?" is usually considered a form of proofreading on EL&U, and therefore off-topic. Here is a [blog entry](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10573/142322) that goes into more detail, and may help you to improve your question. When you [edit] your question, it gets put into a review queue where people can vote to reopen your question.